# How to replace a string with run time value (${jsession}) in Jmeter thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter.

We are using recording controller to capture HTTP requests.

I am extracting the token using the extractor and storing in `${token}`.

I want to replace an alphanumeric string `(ab567cf)` with `${token}` globally inside the thread group.

I have almost 200 HTTP requests to replace.

Can anyone help on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you doing the replacing? In Body Data?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `.jmx` file in a text editor such as Notepad++ and use its find and replace feature.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But can I know if there is any component in jmeter to replace the string (abc567cf) with ${token} automatically for 1000 http requests inside the thread group using some global variables

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be in my opinion to get rid of that value from each request (you can do it manually in jmeter or through some text editor as suggested) and just set it once in proper configuration element, like HTTP Header Manager or HTTP Request Defaults - it depends where do you use that token. If it is sent in the header then put inside the thread group HTTP Header Manager and insert there name of the parameter and ${token} as value. If you send that as request parameter - insert the HTTP Request Defaults and configure it the same as mentioned earlier.
If some of the requests needs some additional parameters or values in header you can add another Header Manager or Request Defaults inside these requests and configure accordingly or just insert that information straight in proper samplers.